# Execute the code inside onDraw() only after the click in view

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ondraw

I have a class that extends a view. 
This class is called in xml to build my view. Now the view call the onDraw automatically the onDraw function on loaded. But how i can do what is do on onDraw() function only after i click in that view?? In conclusion i need to execute the code inside onDraw() only after the click in view.

DrawView.java:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    Context context;

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        // setWillNotDraw(true);

    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        canvas.drawRect((float) (getWidth()*0.3), (float) (getHeight()*0.3), getWidth(), getHeight(), mPaint);
```

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1">    
      <com.example.sliding.DrawView 
            android:id="@+id/tv_listRow_item1"
            android:tag="tv_listRow_item1_1"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:width="100dip"
            android:height="30dip"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_listrow_border"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

main.java:

```
 ((DrawView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_listRow_item1)).setOnClickListener(listener);
  private View.OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: If you want do draw ONLY when you click, then you should not use onDraw() since onDraw() is called whenever your view is invalidated which happens for many reasons.  I suspect that you don't mean ONLY but WHEN.  If so, then just call invalidate() on the view.  If not, then please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hello simon. The view is build in xml. But i need to make a later modifications in the same view when i click. I know that onDraw() execute automatically the code on loaded. But how i can execute the code inside onDraw() WHEN i click the view? Build a new function work is a good aprroache?

Comment: If it's WHEN, then just call invalidate() on your view.  myDrawView.invalidate().  That's it.  No need for more code.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
// your actions here
}
}
```

then call invalidate() function, which will set a flag to call the onDraw() of your view.